# Notification Hub with localized messages

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-phone-8, notifications

i just came up with a new problem but the same context azure. now i am trying to implement Multilinqual(localized) push notifications so i am following this [localized push notification](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/notification-hubs/breaking-news-localized-dotnet/) so this link inculde lot of work of making categories i just wanted to omit them so i am trying to use direct code for subscribing the toast notification on the basis of tag given in Bachend clien app that generate toast notification...here is Backend client app  code..

```
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://samplenotificationhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=", "samplenotificationhub");

        var notification = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        {"News_English", "World News in English!"},
                        {"News_French", "World News in French!"},
                        {"News_Mandarin", "World News in Mandarin!"}};
        await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(notification, "World");
```

first i tried it on my previously working sample app that can receive Push notification on the basis of tags also so i just tried to update its code to get template based toaste notification but unfortunately i am not getting anything..here is the code..

```
private void AcquirePushChannel()
    {
        CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("mychannel");

        if (CurrentChannel == null)
        {
            CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("mychannel");
            CurrentChannel.Open();
            CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();
            CurrentChannel.BindToShellTile();

        }

        CurrentChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(async (o, args) =>
        {
            var tags = new HashSet<string>();
            tags.Add("World");
            var hub = new NotificationHub("samplenotificationhub", "Endpoint=sb://samplenotificationhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=");
            var template = String.Format(@"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">$(News_English)</text></binding></visual></toast>");
            await hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(args.ChannelUri.ToString(),template,"hello", tags);


         //   await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(args.ChannelUri.ToString(),tags);
        });
    }
```

so if you know anything about it..please guide me any kind of help or suggetion is appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Friends I again able to solve my problem so the mistake i am doing here is i am following the link blindly as it is for Windows store apps and i wanted to implemented the same for windows phone 8 so what i am doing wrong is using the same Tamplate that is used in windows store apps for windows phone 8 too. so what i understand is this if wanted to target the multiple platforms from a notification hub then your client app that send the toast notification has the same notification for all but all your platform will handle it differently Like for windows 8 the tamplate i am using will work but windows phone this template will work.

```
 string toast = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
     "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
        "<wp:Toast>" +
             "<wp:Text1>Hello Windows phone</wp:Text1>" +
        "</wp:Toast> " +
     "</wp:Notification>";
```

so different platform will have different platform.hope it help somebody else too.